# JavaFX ScrollPane and Scaling of the Content

Tags: javafx, imageview, scrollpane

I would like to show a photo as an ImageView in a ScrollPane with an ZoomIn and ZoomOut Function. But if I reduce by means of scale the imageview, an undesirable empty edge is created in the ScrollPane. How can you make sure that the ScrollPane is always the size of the **scaled** ImageView?
See the following example. For simplicity, I replaced the ImageView with a rectangle.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollPaneDemo extends Application {

    double scale;
    Pane contPane = new Pane();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
        sp.setContent(contPane);
        sp.setVvalue(0.5);
        sp.setHvalue(0.5);
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(2820, 1240,Color.RED);
        scale = 0.2;
        contPane.setScaleX(scale);
        contPane.setScaleY(scale);

        contPane.getChildren().add(rec);

        Button but1 = new Button("+");        
        but1.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            scale*=2;
            contPane.setScaleX(scale);
            contPane.setScaleY(scale);
        });
        Button but2 = new Button("-");
        but2.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            scale/=2;
            contPane.setScaleX(scale);
            contPane.setScaleY(scale);
        });
        HBox buttons = new HBox(but1, but2);
        pane.setTop(buttons);
        pane.setCenter(sp);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: try Adam Ren's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190029/how-to-effectively-scroll-and-zoom-big-images-in-javafx)

Answer (score 1):

`contPane` scaled by using transform don't change its `layoutBounds` automatically. If you want not to make empty space in `contPane`, you'd better wrap the node in Group.

See this post. [Layout using the transformed bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699623/layout-using-the-transformed-bounds)

```
sp.setContent(new Group(contPane));
```

In addition, if you don't want to make empty space **in ScrollPane**, limit minimum scale to rate which width or height of the content fits viewport's one.

```
Button but1 = new Button("+");
but1.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    updateScale(scale * 2.0d);
});
Button but2 = new Button("-");
but2.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    updateScale(scale / 2.0d);
});
HBox buttons = new HBox(but1, but2);
pane.setTop(buttons);
pane.setCenter(sp);
Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();

updateScale(0.2d);
```

---

```
private void updateScale(double newScale) {
    scale = Math.max(newScale, Math.max(sp.getViewportBounds().getWidth() / rec.getWidth(), sp.getViewportBounds().getHeight() / rec.getHeight()));
    contPane.setScaleX(scale);
    contPane.setScaleY(scale);
}
```

Consider a case of the image is smaller than `ScrollPane`'s viewport. Because for showing no empty space, this code will stretch contents when it doesn't have enough size.

In a case of huge images, TravisF's comment helps you.

Comment: The boxing with the Group helps . Thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue and boxing with the Group helped in zooming but if the Group has many child nodes then rendering the ScrollPane will become slower.